# Woocommerce - Notify admin if customer chooses "Ship to a different address?"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Wanting to send a new order email alert to a different address when someone checks out and has checked "Ship to a different address?".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add a hook in functions.php in your theme folder (if you're using a child theme) or a plugin file.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'email_admin_about_shipping', 10, 1);
function email_admin_about_shipping( $order_id ) {

   if(isset($_POST['ship_to_different_address'])){
       $to = get_option('admin_email');
       wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
   }
}
```

Add in your subject, message etc and this should work for you.

Comment: So like this?

`add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'email_admin_about_shipping', 10, 1);
function email_admin_about_shipping( $order_id ) {

   if(isset($_POST['ship_to_different_address'])){
       $to = get_option('admin_email');
       wp_mail($to= "admin@email.com", $subject="New address order alert", strip_tags($message), $headers);
   }
}`

Sorry haven't sussed markup on here yet. Would this include the new order email info as usual?

Comment: The syntax is correct, but if you want to get new order email info you'll need to add that to the $message variable.